# SymmetricDS sync based on last updated time

Tags: symmetricds

I have 2+ clients + 1 server and I'm able to keep all data synced between clients and server as long as they're all connected. but problem is when a client (laptop) is not online and gets online after a while, in this situation I need to make sure only latest data is synced across databases but now what happens is last connected client's data gets synced to other clients/server even if it's not latest changes and there are newer changes on server/other clients.

I appreciate if you can help me solve this.

Comment: are the clients and the server having in sync internal clocks? is IT really necessary to have the syncing based on last updated time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find the answer

I added a load filter record and used following bsh script to filter_on_update column to avoid changes with older modified date value

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S", Locale.ENGLISH);
if (format.parse(MODIFIED).after(format.parse(OLD_MODIFIED))) {
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
```